# Is it possible to see deleted answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Someone posted an incorrect answer and later deleted it after I posted a correct answer. Is there any way for me to see the deleted answer, or is it gone forever?

Answer (score 6):

Deleted answers can be seen by:

- The owner of the answer.
- Users with 10k+ reputation.
- Moderators.

Comment: Okay, good to know--thanks. Guess I better get busy and start earning more points if I want to see 'em ;)

Comment: @MPW Or get elected <s>cat herder</s> moderator.

Comment: Hmm, no strikethrough in comments?

Comment: @AlexBecker [Requested long ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31228/251274), not declined but (it seems) not planned  to be implemented, either. If implemented, it would be Markdown's ---triple dash--- , not HTML. There is <b>no</b> HTML support in comments.